# No rows in Data Set in VB.Net using MSACCESS

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
 Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CMP.accdb"
    connection.Open()
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT IDDesc FROM [ItemDesc] WHERE IDPartNo = " & PartNoTxt.Text & ";", connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "FilteredDesc")
    connection.Dispose()
    connection = Nothing
    DescTxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
```

I'm putting 20-0015175 at PartNoTxt, and I have the same IDPartNo in my database. But it is not returning any row in my dataset. Anyone know what the problem is? "There is no row at position 0." I think my problem is withing the WHERE clause in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Changed the:

`" & PartNoTxt.Text & "`

to:

`'" & PartNoTxt.Text & "'`